# Constructing Java object from RDF file

Tags: java, xml-parsing, rdf

I have the following [RDF](http://dati.beniculturali.it/dataset/dataset-luoghi.rdf) file described [here](http://dati.beniculturali.it/cultural-ON/ENG.html#d4e4238) and I want to create Java Objects starting from it. Do I have to parse the entire file or is there a way to map the statements of the file to classes and attributes? I'm trying to use jena to collect Statements but all I get are triples with URLs which are useless unless I parse them. I also have a turtle version of the same file but I don't know if it's better.

Comment: I think you could google something like "rdf 2 pojo".

Comment: [Jena Schemagen](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/tools/schemagen.html) does something in that direction